# Grid Search in Multi class classification problems using Neural networks

Tags: neural-network, grid-search

I'm trying to do grid search for a multi class problem in neural networks.
I am not able to get the optimum parameters, the kernel keeps on compiling.
Is there any problem with my code? Please do help

```
import keras

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# defining the baseline model:

def neural(output_dim=10,init_mode='glorot_uniform'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=output_dim,
                    input_dim=2,
                    activation='relu',
                    kernel_initializer= init_mode))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=output_dim,
                    activation='relu',
                    kernel_initializer= init_mode))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=3,activation='softmax'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=neural, 
                            epochs=5, 
                            batch_size=5, 
                            verbose=0)

# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
init_mode = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 
             'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']
output_dim = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30,40]

param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, 
                  epochs=epochs,
                  output_dim=output_dim,
                  init_mode=init_mode)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, 
                    scoring= 'accuracy',
                    param_grid=param_grid, 
                    n_jobs=-1,cv=5)

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# summarize results

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, 
                             grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Comment: First always try with n_jobs=1 to see if its working correct on not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error in your code.

Your current param grid has 864 different combinations of parameters possible.

(6 values in `'batch_size'` × 3 values in `'epochs'`  ×  8 in `'init_mode'`  ×  6 in `'output_dim'`) = 864

GridSearchCV will iterate over all those possibilities and your estimator will be cloned that many times. And that is again repeated 5 times because you have set `cv=5`.

So your model will be cloned (compiled and params set according to the possibilities) a total of 864 x 5 = 4320 times.

So you keep seeing in output that the model is being compiled those many times.

To check if GridSearchCV is working or not, use its `verbose` param.

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, 
                    scoring= 'accuracy',
                    param_grid=param_grid, 
                    n_jobs=1,cv=5, verbose=3)
```

This will print the current possible params being tried, the cv iteration, time taken to fit on it, current accuracy etc.

Comment: Hi Vivek ,much thanks for the reply. I am taking the target variable Y without   one hot encoding it as I had tried to one hot encode the target variable and tried to fit in Grid search, but an error was being shown. I have now fitted the grid search model with Target variable without being one hot encoded. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: @arjunanil705 It depends on loss. Since you are using `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, no need to one-hot encode, passing them without one hot encoding is the correct way.